# bash fetch first field awk grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cut

In my brctl show command :

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
olm-com_uim     8000.b8ca3a5ecab1   no      eth1
                            vnet1


tyy-fom_psr     8000.a0369f11b218   no      bond1103
                            vnet0
                            vnet10
                            vnet8
uuu-r8s_udm     8000.b8o        eth1.1621
                            vnet5
bbb-r8s_ptr     8000.b8c    no      bond1115
```

I just want to grep :

```
olm-com_uim
tyy-fom_psr
uuu-r8s_udm 
bbb-r8s_ptr
```

So I try this,

```
brctl show | grep -v vnet | grep -v bridge | awk '{print $1}'
```

But I think, its is no very well method

Comment: Perhaps `brctl show | awk '$1 != "bridge" && /^[^[:space:]]/ { print $1 }'`?

Comment: You should mention that your fields are tab-separated, I had to edit your question to discover that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `grep -o` as well:

```
brctl show | tail -n +2 | grep -o '^[^[:blank:]]\+'
```

```
olm-com_uim
tyy-fom_psr
uuu-r8s_udm
bbb-r8s_ptr
```

Regex `^[^[:blank:]]\+` matches 1+ non-whitespace characters at the line start.

Comment: sorry, i forget the bridge name, you command give me bridge name, plz see edit section

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '!/^ / && NF{print $1}' file

olm-com_uim
tyy-fom_psr
uuu-r8s_udm
bbb-r8s_ptr
```

if not starting with empty and not blank line print first field.  If you want to skip header add `&& NR>1`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR>1 && $1{print $1}' file
olm-com_uim
tyy-fom_psr
uuu-r8s_udm
bbb-r8s_ptr
```

or if your fields weren't tab-separated:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && /^[^[:space:]]/{print $1}' file
olm-com_uim
tyy-fom_psr
uuu-r8s_udm
bbb-r8s_ptr
```

Answer (score 0):

`brctl` output from my dev box. You should get the desired result with the following command.

```
$ brctl show | awk 'NF>1 && NR>1{print $1}'
br0
docker0
virbr0
virbr1
virbr2
virbr3
```

`NF>1` is needed to filter out the `vnet` interfaces that follows the bridge interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers. Here's sed:

```
brctl show | sed -e 1d -nre 's/^([^[:blank:]]+).*/\1/p'
```